# Difference between dot operator and fully qualified named call in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure. Still I have no good understanding
for the language and the philosophy.

But I want to be more familiar with the language. Hence 
I have started to read Clojure core API documentation
and found some interesting stuffs in `clojure.core/get` source code.

```
(defn get
  "Returns the value mapped to key, not-found or nil if key not present."
  {:inline (fn  [m k & nf] `(. clojure.lang.RT (get ~m ~k ~@nf)))
   :inline-arities #{2 3}
   :added "1.0"}
  ([map key]
   (. clojure.lang.RT (get map key)))
  ([map key not-found]
   (. clojure.lang.RT (get map key not-found))))
```

To get a value with given key the code uses `clojurelang.RT/get` function.
The code calls dot operator - `(. clojure.lang.RT (get map key))`.

My question is why the author wrote `(. clojure.lang.RT (get map key))` instead of 
`(clojure.lang.RT/get map key)`.

Is there any technical difference? or any benefit?

Comment: Has the `classname/method` syntax been defined prior to the definition?  My guess would be that `clojure.lang.RT/get` would be a syntax error at this point in compilation.

Comment: ``clojure.core`` code is probably not a good place to start for understanding the language philosophy, because it tends to use the lowest level forms. You'd be better looking at well established libraries like ring for a clean HTTP abstraction (https://github.com/mmcgrana/ring/) or compojure for a routing DSL (https://github.com/weavejester/compojure)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dot in Clojure is used for host interop (with the Java class clojure.lang.RT in this case). The idiomatic form for a static method is `(Classname/staticMethod args*)` but that gets expanded into a call on the `.` special form. In the case of the `get` function, you're essentially looking at a part of Clojure's implementation. There's no reason why the lower-level Clojure code would use the higher level macro - so it uses the `.` form directly.

Take a look at the documentation at: http://clojure.org/java_interop

The idiomatic forms are at the top and below you can find how they're expanded into calls on the dot operator. Here's the relevant bit for static methods:

```
(Classname/staticMethod args*) ==> (. Classname staticMethod args*)
```